# Getting Body content from MSMQ

Tags: c#, msmq

I try to get the content of an item in a MSMQ - Queue.

When I look at that Entry using QueueExplorer the body content is like

```
[{"$type":"MyProject.MyClass.MyMethod, Messages","CustomerDecision":0,"OrderReferenceoId":"4fdb6be2-bfde-42b0-93fd-47058a326a24"}]
```

When I try to read the content using the following code, the body just contains weird crap, mostly \0\0 etc.:

```
message.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(); 
var reader = new StreamReader(message.BodyStream);
var msgBody = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

(message is of type System.Messaging.Message)

Comment: Why are you using an XmlMessageFormatter for content serialized as Json? In the same way that you must have serialized an object to get it to appear like this in the body, you need to deserialize it on the way back out of the queue.

Comment: I do NOT know how the content is serialized at that point. I just want to receive the pure text. The QueueExplorer cannot know the format either.  (I also tried BinaryMessageFormatter with the same results)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a Coding Issue. The result LOOKED like random rubbish, but just was a unicode characterset. The following solved the problem:

```
message.Formatter = new BinaryMessageFormatter();
var reader = new StreamReader(message.BodyStream, Encoding.Unicode);
var msgBody = reader.ReadToEnd();
```